# React Navigation Tab.Screen set Component as name

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What i want to do is the following when using the react navigation package.
The docs allow the following:

```
<Tab.Screen name="name" component={FeedScreen} />
```

what i want to achieve is this:

```
<Tab.Screen name={<NameMarkdown />} component={FeedScreen} />
```

because i want to render markdown as the name of a tab in my application.

is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name prop only accepts the string name of the screen you can't pass the component into a name prop.

To give customize the style of your tab you can use it like this

```
     <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={tabScreenOptions}
            tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}
          >
         <Tab.Screen name="name" component={FeedScreen} />
    
    tabBarOptions = {
      showLabel: false,
      style: styles.tabContainer,
      tabStyle: styles.tabStyle,
    };
    
    tabScreenOptions = props => {
      const { route } = props;
      return {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabIcon {...{ route, focused }} />,
      };
    };
    
    const TabIcon = ({ focused, route }) => (
  // Here you can use your own component according to your need
      <Image
        source={Images.tabs[route.name]}
        style={{ tintColor: focused ? Colors.primary : Colors.white214 }}
      />
    );
```

Hope this helps you out.